# How do I get the highest number in a column?

Tags: php, mysql

My table named **pictures** has a column named **pic** and I'm wanting to get the highest number in that column. Each row has a unique number in **pic** and it goes up by *1* each row. But one or two rows won't have a number in the column and will have some text instead. Like **grapes**.

Here's an example of the table...

```
  TABLE: pictures
 ___________________
|  caption  |  pic  |
|-------------------|
|   some    |   1   |
|  random   |   2   |
|  thing    |   3   |
|   here    |grapes |
|___________________|
```

So, how would I get the highest number in the column **pic** which would be **3**?

Column **pic** is a **varchar**.

Comment: A bit of a tangent, but it seems a bit of a worry that numbers and strings are mixed together in one column like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(CONVERT(pic, UNSIGNED INTEGER)) AS max_pic
FROM pictures
WHERE CONVERT(pic, UNSIGNED INTEGER) IS NOT NULL
```

<strike>The `WHERE pic = pic + 0` condition is a trick that helps checking if it is a number value</strike>

Comment: Sorry, it selects **grapes**.

Comment: @Skiroid: another fix is applied ;-)

Comment: MySQL sucks in that you cannot apply aliases to WHERE clause. Nice answer with the converting of type.

Comment: @Mike Purcell: sql server, postgresql and oracle dbms also don't allow using aliases in `WHERE` as well. I think that's caused by optimizer requiremenets

Comment: @zerkms: Interesting. Just seems counter-intuitive to do the same logic multiple times.

Comment: @zerkms: I don't really want to nag you with another question but I'm going to do it anyway :D since you clearly know what you're doing.

If I wanted to echo the number in PHP how would I do it?

What I have at the moment gives me echo's out **Resource id #3**. Here's what I've got now...

`mysql_select_db("skiroid_lulzorg", $mysqlconnect);
$highestpic = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(CONVERT(pic, UNSIGNED INTEGER)) AS max_pic FROM pictures WHERE CONVERT(pic, UNSIGNED INTEGER) IS NOT NULL");
echo $highestpic;`

I'd have thought that would be it. If you don't know, I'll search/ask elsewhere. Thanks.

Comment: @Skiroid: look at http://php.net/mysql_query. What `mysql_query` returns is a resource, and you need to fetch the data from it

Answer (score 1):

Use `MAX()` to get the maximum value available. Like this

```
SELECT MAX(pic) FROM `pictures` WHERE CONVERT(`pic`, SIGNED INTEGER) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: What if he has `0` value and it is the only value? ;-) But indeed, in most cases it would work

Comment: Sorry but, I'm trying it in phpMyAdmin and it selects the text one. Which would be **grapes**.

Comment: `SELECT MAX(pic) FROM pictures WHERE ABS(pic) >= 0;` Still selects **grapes** :S

Comment: My actual column has numbers from 1 to 20 with one with text (21 rows in total) at the moment. New rows will be inserted so the highest number will grow. `SELECT MAX(pic) FROM 'pictures' WHERE pic REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$';` brings me the value **9**.

Comment: @Skiroid, if 1 to 20 is the only case, then pic >= 1 should do it

Comment: @Skiroid, Now? the zerkms got it

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql:

```
SELECT MAX(pic) FROM pictures
```

Depending on the column type you will get different results.

Comment: The column type is a **varchar**. It selects **grapes** :(